# For which $\alpha$ does $\int_E \frac{x^\alpha}{\sqrt{x^4+y^2}}$ converges?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Where $E$ is the area of the circle $x^2+(y-1)^2=1$ minus the area of a second circle $x^2+(y-0.5)^2=0.5^2$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problematic point is around $(x,y)=(0,0)$. By symmetry, it is sufficient to only consider $x>0$.

Let's write the integral on the small area in $E$ close to $(0,0)$ but on the right of $x$ as
$$I=\int_0^{x_\text{max}}dx\int_{y_{\text{min}}(x)}^{y_{\text{max}}(x)}dy\,\frac{x^\alpha}{\sqrt{x^4+y^2}}$$
Here, $y_{\text{min}}(x)$ and $y_{\text{max}}(x)$ are the bottom ordinates of the two circles at abscissa $x$. You may choose $x_\text{max}$ as any positive value smaller than $\frac12$. One has
$$y_{\text{min}}(x)=1-\sqrt{1-x^2}\sim \frac12x^2,\qquad y_{\text{max}}(x)=\frac12-\sqrt{\frac14-x^2}\sim x^2$$
(the equivalents are given as $x\searrow0$.)

So, at this point, your integral on $E$ converges if and only if the integral $I$ converges, and $I$ has only a potential problem in the outer integral for the lower bound $x=0$.

Now compute the inner integral
$$I=\int_0^{x_\text{max}}dx\,x^\alpha \Big[\text{argsinh}\frac{y_\text{max}(x)}{x^2}-\text{argsinh}\frac{y_\text{min}(x)}{x^2}\Big]$$
As $x\to0$, the expression in brackets converges to $\text{argsinh}\,1-\text{argsinh}\frac12$, and so $I$ (and $E$) converges iff the integral of $x^\alpha$ converges at 0, that is iff
$$\alpha>-1$$

Comment: @user1533006 Thank you for the explanation, really helped me!

Comment: You're welcome. Thinking again about it, I think there should be an absolute value around $x$ in $x^\alpha$ in your question.